# Safari flexbox: child of flex container with height:100% overflows when it has a grandchild with height:100%

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I have this code here and it behaves differently in Safari than in Chrome and Firefox, why?

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: salmon;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
}

.grandchild2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="grandchild2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Safari 12.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOIQZ.png)

[Chrome 79.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNyt6.png)

[Firefox 70.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z96o7.png)

I don't understand why the presence of `grandchild2` makes `child2` to have the same height as `parent`. Is this a known Safari bug?

If I remove `grandchild2`, `child2` doesn't overflow.

Is there a workaround to make Safari behave like Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 1` and / or `min-height: 0` to `.child2`.

Comment: @Michael_B by doing this, both `child2` and `grandchild2` have a height of `0px`, in Chrome and Safari.
See https://jsfiddle.net/96pL5hky/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `child2` a flex container seems to make bring the behaviour that I expect.

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: salmon;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: grey;
  flex-grow: 1; /* <---- added that */
  display: flex; /* <---- added that */
  flex-direction: column; /* <---- added that */
}

.grandchild2 {
  flex-grow: 1; /* <---- added that */
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="grandchild2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After reading this thread: [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent)

It seems that I have to use flex all the way through and not mix `height: 100%` and `flex-grow:1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing height from child2 and use instead flex-grow: 1

Comment: Still different from Chrome.
With `.child2 { background: grey; flex-grow: 1}` like you suggested, the height of `grandchild2` is `0px` in Safari and `132px` in Chrome.

Comment: I added `background: blue` to my snippet to make this more visible. What you suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/0aekrm5d/